# How to override a grails dynamic finder?

Tags: grails, caching, dynamic-finders

Say I have a class `Person` with a `name` field. I can do a `Person.findByName` but what if I want to override this method to ensure that the query is cached? How do I override this dynamic finder method?

Comment: Don't. Use a service and cache the method on the service. That's the correct way to implement this pattern.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Should it be equivalent if I have Person.forName that does the same thing as you suggested to do on the service?

Comment: You can implement static method in domain class.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write:

```
Person.findByName("some-name", [cache: true])
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But what I want is to change 'Person.findByName("some-name")' so that it is cacheable query by default. Don't want a coder to remember to add ', [cache: true]' wherever the dynamic finder is used.